# 3x3 Average filter in C#

Tags: c#, image

I've written code to smooth an image,it's using 3x3 averaging filter. But seem it's not working
The picture output almost black

```
public void Smooth(Bitmap bmpInput){

        Bitmap temp;

        Color c;
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmpInput.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpInput.Height; j++)
            {
                c = bmpInput.GetPixel(i, j);
                byte gray = (byte)(.333 * c.R + .333 * c.G + .333 * c.B); 
                bmpInput.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray));
            }
        }
        temp = bmpInput;
      for (int i = 0; i <= bmpInput.Width - 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= bmpInput.Height - 3; j++)
            {
                for (int x = i; x <= i + 2; x++)
                    for (int y = j; y <= j + 2; y++)
                    {
                        c = bmpInput.GetPixel(x,y);
                        sum = sum +  c.R ;
                    }
                int color = (int)Math.Round(sum/9,10);
                temp.SetPixel(i + 1, j + 1, Color.FromArgb(color, color, color));
                sum = 0;
            }
        bmpInput = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `temp`still refers to the exact same bitmap. You have to assign `temp`to new Bitmap image and work with this. Alternatively, you can store the new pixel values in a temporary array and transfer the contents of this array back to the image afterwards.